# Finding a point having some property

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a fixed continuous function such that $f$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$ and $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Then show that there is at least one $x\in[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=f'(x)$.

Can we solve this using mean value theorem or is there any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take $g(x)=f(x)e^{-x}$ then clearly $g(0)=g(1)=0$ so $g'(c)=0$ for some $c\in (0,1)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: How did you get the idea of such function?

Comment: I saw $f'(x)=f(x)$ and immediately thought of $e^x$.